# Why are the following trivial self-equalities needed in the Isabelle/Isar proof?

Tags: isabelle

I am trying to learn isabelle/Isar and make sense out of the following simple proof about `mod` from `Rings.thy`. I made a copy of the type class to avoid clashing with the original:

```
class semiring_modulo1 = comm_semiring_1_cancel + divide + modulo +
  assumes div_mult_mod_eq: "a div b * b + a mod b = a"
begin
```

Then this is the lemma whose proof confuses me. The first line makes sense as it uses a previous theorem and rewrites it by symmetry. But the next two lines look really strange. Each of them states the same thing equals itself (e.g. `"a div b = a div b"`). They seem useless/meaningless. They do not connect to the `q` or `r` in the lemma to prove (`q` and `r` were never mentioned in the proof).

```
lemma mod_div_decomp:
  fixes a b
  obtains q r where "q = a div b" and "r = a mod b"
    and "a = q * b + r"
proof -
  from div_mult_mod_eq have "a = a div b * b + a mod b" by simp
  moreover have "a div b = a div b" ..
  moreover have "a mod b = a mod b" ..
  note that ultimately show thesis by blast
qed
```

My questions are:

Why are these empty equalities necessary (and leaving them out breaks the proof)?

What is the equivalent statement of these in English/Mizar?

Are there alternative ways in Isar to write the proof in a way that is closer to English (e.g. take q = a div b ...)?

Answer (score 1):

They're not necessary. It's just that the rule `that` (which is produced by the `obtains` keyword) looks like this:

```
?q1 = a div b ⟹ ?r1 = a mod b ⟹ a = ?q1 * b + ?r1 ⟹ thesis
```

This is the usual encoding of existential statements in higher-order logic. The `a div b = a div b` and `a mod b = a mod b` simply provides hints to `blast` about how to instantiate the first two assumptions. However, it seems that this is not really needed, it also works without these two trivial equalities.

In any case, even if I had wanted to give instantiation hints, I probably would have done it with `that[of "a div b" "a mod b"]` or `that[OF refl refl]` instead.

That said, I'm not really sure why this lemma exists in the first place. The assumptions seem kind of vacuous.