# What does the "note" command do in Isabelle and when is it necessary?

Tags: isabelle, isar

I am trying to learn the Isar language (as of Isabelle 2020), and understand the `note` command. It seems to be a fundamental element of the language since a lot of the "Derived elements" are defined based on it.

I am not sure what it does in terms of the equivalents of English:

1. When it is necessary to `note` something? Aren't all the facts and/or assumptions known at this point of time automatically used, or do I have to explicit `note` certain facts before I can use them? If so, which ones do and do not need to be `note`d?
2. What are the things to be noted?

In the documentation Isar-ref.PDF, appendix A1.2 (pp319), under "Primitives", it says:

> note a = b    reconsider and declare facts

so it seems that an equality is to be noted.
Then, in A 1.3 in the same page, it says:

```
from a ≡ note a then
...
from this ≡ then
```

Here `note` doesn't seem to work on an equality. Also, there seems to be a endless loop.

```
from a = note a then = note a from this = note a note this then ...
```

(`then` expands to `from` and back to `then`).

then on the same page, there is:

```
also   ~   note calculation = this
```

*In English, the word "also" (and to some extent "note that") is optional*. This is partly why it is so confusing to me here because it seems to be required, and I am not sure what it does. (I can understand other things such as `assume` as it moves some facts into the context.)

I've seen `this` and `that` used in a `note` command (e.g. in here [Why are the following trivial self-equalities needed in the Isabelle/Isar proof?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65786736)). This confused me a lot.

*Is there a dictionary (English dictionary) style explanation somewhere in terms of what `note` does on the things (`this`, `that`, `calculation` etc.)?*

*,... and why is `note` required?*

(The above appendix is the closest thing to a specification I could find.)

Answer (score 2):

No one ever uses that in the way of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65786736/why-are-the-following-trivial-self-equalities-needed-in-the-isabelle-isar-proof). It hurts to look at that proof. The Isar ref is telling you how things are defined internally, but it is a *terrible* introduction to Isar. Don't read it. Forget everything you read there. Really.

The right way to start Isar is the prog-prove. Or slides used for teaching.

No facts are used implicitly. Isabelle only uses the facts that you tell it to use. That is why you need `using` or to pass theorems as argument to tactics.

The usual way to use `note` is to give a name to something that does not have a name yet, like:

```
   case Suc
   note meaningfull_name_one = this(1) and meaningfull_name_two = this(2)
```

or variants of that. This allows you to refer to theorems by name `meaningfull_name_one` instead of writing down the full expression. It is not necessary, but easier (also maintenance-wise). When you have 10 assumptions, you don't want to use `prems(1)` or `Suc(8)` or whatever.

As mentioned @ManuelEberl

```
note [simp] = ...
```

is useful to locally declare a theorem as simp.

Short summary:

```
   this           ::= last fact
   note H = ...   ::= name facts
   that           ::= name of the fact generate by obtain/obtain
```

Don't ever use `calculation` directly.

It is possible to abuse note like in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65786736/why-are-the-following-trivial-self-equalities-needed-in-the-isabelle-isar-proof), by not giving a name to things and relying on its side effects. Don't do it.

Comment: I often use it to declare things as e.g. simp rules as well: `note [simp] = my_equation`. Or very occasionally also when I have an already proven equation I want to use in an `also` chain: `have "a = b" by some_method also note ‹b = c› finally have "a = c"`

Comment: Also, while Mathias is quite correct in saying that *Isar* does not use facts implicitly, specific proof methods (like `simp`, `auto`) do use facts implicitly, e.g. those that have been declared `simp` or `intro`.

Comment: Isar also uses e.g. `trans` rules explicitly when you do an `also` chain.

Comment: @ManuelEberl My impression from teaching is that people believe (or expect) that assumptions are used in the later `have`s. But you are obviously right that simp is doing things implicitly.

Comment: While I agree that Isar-ref may not be the best introduction to Isar, `Don't read it. Forget everything you read there. Really.` sounds very excessive for an answer on SO and, overall, in my view, may not be the best advice. From my own experience, while I started learning Isar from the textbooks, without supplementing my learning with Isar-ref, most likely, I would have struggled more than I have. Sorry for being a pain, but I could not resist :-).

Comment: It's a valid opinion, but I would tend to agree with Mathias that learning Isar from the reference manual is probably going to be painful and I would not recommend it.

Comment: @Mathias: Yes, I thought as much (that's how e.g. Mizar does it, I think), I just wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

One reason is that you can create new theorems with low-level operations such as [OF _]. To simplify reusing such a theorem, you can give it a name.