# How to prove a thereom about a type class outside the original type class definition?

Tags: typeclass, isabelle

I was trying alternative ways to write the below proof from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65786736) and Isabelle 2020's `Rings.thy`. (In particular, I added the `note div_mult_mod_eq[of a b]` line to test the use of the `note` command:

```
lemma mod_div_decomp:
  fixes a b
  obtains q r where "q = a div b" and "r = a mod b"
    and "a = q * b + r"
proof -
  from div_mult_mod_eq have "a = a div b * b + a mod b" by simp
  note div_mult_mod_eq[of a b]
  moreover have "a div b = a div b" ..
  moreover have "a mod b = a mod b" ..
  note that ultimately show thesis by blast
qed
```

However, if I write it in a separate `.thy` file, there is an error about type unification at the `note` line:

```
Type unification failed: Variable 'a::{plus,times} not of sort semiring_modulo

Failed to meet type constraint:

Term:  a :: 'a
Type:  ??'a
```

The problem goes way if I enclose the whole proof in a pair of type class `class begin ... end` as follows:

```
theory "test"
  imports Main 
  HOL.Rings
 begin
  ...

    class semiring_modulo = comm_semiring_1_cancel + divide + modulo +
      assumes div_mult_mod_eq: "a div b * b + a mod b = a"
    begin
     (* ...  inserted proof here *)
    end

 ... 
end
```

My questions are:

*Is this the correct way to prove a theorem about a type class? i.e. to write a separate class definition in a different file?*

*Is it always necessary to duplicate type class definitions as I did?*

*If not, what is the proper way to prove a theorem about a type class outside of its original place of definition?*

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to prove things in type classes (basically sort = typeclass for Isabelle/HOL):

1. Proving in the context of the typeclass

```
context semiring_modulo
begin
...
end
```

2. (slightly less clean) Add the sort constraints to the type:

```
lemma mod_div_decomp:
  fixes a b :: "'a :: {semiring_modulo}"
  obtains q r where "q = a div b" and "r = a mod b"
    and "a = q * b + r"
```

`semiring_modulo` subsumes `plus` and `times`, but you can also type `{semiring_modulo,plus,times}` to really have all of them.

The [documentation of classes](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2020/doc/classes.pdf) contains more examples.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you ran into is related to how Isabelle implements polymorphism. Sorts represent a subset of all types, and we characterize them by a set of intersected classes. By attaching a sort to a variable, we restrict the space of terms with which that variable can be instantiated with. One way of looking at this is an assumption that the variable belongs to a certain sort. In your case, type inference `(+)` `(*)` `div` `mod` apparently gives you `{plus,times}`, which is insufficient for `div_mult_mod_eq`. To restrict the variable further you can make an explicit type annotation as Mathias explained.
Note that the simp in the line above should run into the same problem.