# what's the distinction between `shows` and `obtains` in Isabelle Isar?

Tags: isabelle, isar

I am trying to understand the difference between the `shows` and `obtains` commands in Isar (as of Isabelle 2020). The documentation in `isar-ref.pdf` (pp 137.) seems to have some typo and confuses me.

> ...
> Moreover, there are two kinds of conclusions: shows states several
> simultaneous propositions (essentially a big conjunction), while
> obtains claims several simultaneous simultaneous contexts of
> (essentially a big disjunction of eliminated parameters and
> assumptions, cf. §6.6).

`shows` seems straight forward.

From the limited experience I have so far, it seems that `obtains` is about proving a conclusion that begins with an existential quantifier, as shown [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65786736) (where the conclusion is existential and then the goal is a `obtains`).

*Is this really the distinction between `shows` and `obtains` (universal vs existential)?*

*If not, what is the proper intended use of `obtains`?*

Comment: `obtains` is the version of `obtain` that works right after lemmas, like `shows`/`show` or  `assumes`/`assume`. Makarius did not pick the names by accident. Do you understand the explanation of `obtain` in the prog-prove?

Comment: @MathiasFleury Thanks for the hints. The examples of  `obtain` in `prog-prove` (among others) are the first thing I read. I couldn't understand because they are *somewhat magical*. The examples themselves work but I often couldn't get it to work on other data. There is usually no further analysis than the working examples. I guess the example set isn't large enough to cover all the combinations in practice. Hence the questions about its grammar, e.g. whether `obtains` translate to existential quantification etc., so that I can understand the semantics in ordinary mathematical sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lemmas "shows ‹∃x. P x›" and "obtains x where ‹P x›` are very similar, but not entirely identical.

In terms of proofs, the obtain version requires to find an explicit witness (look the fact called `that` in such a proof). Something similar can be achieved by applying the theorem `exI` after the shows.

The generated lemmas are different. The `obtains` version generates an elimination rule instead of a quantified, because there is no existential quantifier in Pure. However, the difference rarely matters when using the theorem.